# Make WebBrowser control use linked stylesheet in DocumentText

Tags: c#, css, browser

I'm using a WebBrowser control and the text displays but it isn't using the linked css, it just appears as plain text.
I'm populating it like so

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = some_text;
```

In some_text is `<link rel="stylesheet"href="PF.css">` along with the rest of the html

When I save some_text to a file and have the WebBrowser navigate to it it works fine
`webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\test.html");` and PF.css is in C:\

I've put PF.css in my project folder, where all the class files are.

How can I make the WebBrowser control use/display my linked css file?
I don't want to save off my string to a file and then navigate to it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument CurrentDocument = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
 mshtml.IHTMLStyleSheet styleSheet = CurrentDocument.createStyleSheet("", 0);
 StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\PF.css");
 string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
 streamReader.Close();
 styleSheet.cssText = text;
```

kind of a krapy way to do it, but everything I read seems to point to the webbrowser control can't do css unless you Navigate to a file/url and it's included in there.
BTW you have to add a ref to Microsoft.mshtml.

Maybe future versions of this control could handle linked stylesheets...

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline style as..

```
<html>
   <head>
       <style>
           // all my style here
       </style>
   </head>
<body>
..
..
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by put it in your project folder, do you mean your `bin` folder, or the folder with the `.sln` file in it? If it's the latter, you have to put it in the same folder as your executable (e.g. `bin/Debug/PF.css`, `bin/Release/PF.css`, etc).

Alternatively, you can embed it in the HTML using a `<style type="text/css"><!-- CSS Here --></style>`, and replace the comment with your CSS. If you don't want to hardcode it in where ever you get `some_text` from, you can dynamically replace it by loading `PF.css`:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("PF.css"))
{
    some_text = String.Format(some_text, sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

That example assumes `some_text` contains the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    {0}
</style>
```

Comment: I originally put it with the .cs files
I tried putting PF.css in bin/Debug and it still doesn't work

the inline css isn't an option

Comment: See my edits. By the way, you would put `PF.css` in the `bin/Debug` folder if you're using the Debug configuration, if you're using Release, it would be in `bin/Release`, etc.

Comment: I'm in debug mode, stepping through the code.
PF.css is in bin/Debug, doesn't work.

I've tried your streamreader example, but it doesn't work, same plain text

I'm wondering if .DomumentText is the correct way to add css...